# What is the philosophy behind the workspaces in R?

Tags: r, workspace, setwd

When I start R session from some directory, R automatically loads the corresponding workspace (if it exists). After I finish to work in this workspace I can decide if I want to modify (save) the current workspace. This logic is simple and clear.

What I do not understand, is what happens if I start R from some directory and then change the working directory by `setwd()`. As far as I understood the workspace corresponding to the new working directory will not be "loaded". I still see the variables and history from the previous working directory. Why?

Second, when I `quit()` R, I replace the work-space image corresponding to the "new" working directory by the workspace corresponding to the "old" directory. Do I interpret the behavior correctly? What is the logic behind this behavior? Can I switch to another work-space from R session?

Comment: We can disable automatic restore options for project/sourcedocs/.RData from menu `Tools > Options`. Saving environment as [a Project](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects) is great when we want to come back to exactly where we left off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workspaces are stored in .RData files and are automatically loaded from current working directory when you start R. But working directory itself (and `setwd()` function that sets it) has nothing to do with workspace. You can load any workspace by explicitly specifying any .RData file:

```
load("c:/project/myfile.RData")
```

or

```
setwd("c:/project/")
load()
```

Comment: Yes, because `setwd()` is ran after any `load()`.

Comment: If you use Rstudio or statet and create project you should not be worry about the workspace.

Comment: RStudio is asking whether you wish to save workspace image before quitting. Personally, I prefer not to save the workspace most of the time, because it quickly becomes huge when you researching something with big datasets, and takes many time\space to save-load.

Comment: When I interpreted the results of my play-around correctly, the working directory and works-spaces are not totally "orthogonal" (independent). I have seen that the image of the current works spaces is set in the working directory that I set. Let say I started R from directory `test1` the corresponding work-space has been loaded automatically, then I used `setwd` to set the working directory value to `test2` and then, when I quit R, the current work-space is saved in `test2` directory.

Comment: Yes, `save()` and `load()` functions that are called under the hood when R is started\quitted are using current WD, but changing WD itself doesn't cause any workspace manipulations.